# pythonic way of expressing set with infinite number

Tags: python, set

I'm leading a python study group in a couple of weekends and thought I would go over some simple discrete math ideas, starting with sets. Is there pythonic way of expressing a set like

A = {x| -inf < x < 6}

a simple boolean val of `n < 6` will obviously work, but wondering if there is a way to make it into a set object so I can call do stuff like `n in myset` and `mysubset.issubset(myset)` and the like.

thanks

Comment: You can define a class, and then define the `__contains__()` method to implement the `in` operator.

Comment: You might want to check whether `sympy` already has something like this.

Comment: There are sympy sets: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html